# Updating the state of object of key:value (array) in React

Tags: reactjs

```
applied_filters: { title: [''], owner: [''], customer: [''] }
```

One of the states that I have looked like above. I tried to use `setState` to add value to one of the keys by doing

```
this.setState({
  applied_filters: [
      ...this.state.applied_filters,
      {title: [...this.state.applied_filters.title, optionItem.option]}
  ]
})
```

This gives me an error `this.state.applied_filters is not iterable`

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: Can you post the full code? How is this rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your first code, `applied_filters` is an object: `applied_filters: { title: [''], owner: [''], customer: [''] }`.

However, in the `setState` call it's being converted to an array (not an object). Try keeping it as an object?

```
this.setState({
  applied_filters: {
    ...this.state.applied_filters,
    title: [...this.state.applied_filters.title, optionItem.option]
  }
});
```

Comment: @Dawn17 would you mark it as an answer if it has solved your issue?